# Arduino ignoring the first message and responding only to subsequent messages

Tags: python, arduino, serial-port, pyserial

I am using the following code that uses PySerial to communicate with an Arduino.

```
def test_without_thread(port, msg):
    ser = serial.Serial(port, baudrate=115200, timeout=1.)

    for i in range(10):
        ser.write(msg)
        print i, ser.readline().strip("\r\n")
```

which when run with

```
msg = "q02i15i21"
port = "/dev/ttyACM1"
test_without_thread(port, msg)
```

gives the following output:

```
0 
1 oi1+1023003+i2+103+
2 oi1+1023003+i2+103+
3 oi1+1023003+i2+103+
4 oi1+1023003+i2+103+
5 oi1+1023003+i2+103+
6 oi1+1023003+i2+103+
7 oi1+1023003+i2+103+
8 oi1+1023003+i2+103+
9 oi1+1023003+i2+103+
```

If I sleep before the first write (right before the loop), all of the requests timeout. I do have a small sleep of 10ms after `serial.Begin()` in my Arduino code.

My Arduino code (relevant parts) is as follows:

```
volatile unsigned int interlock_state = OPEN;

float get_ext_ilk(){
  return (float) interlock_state;
}

void dummyFunc(float set_value){
  Serial.println("Called the dummy function!");
}

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(115200);
  delay(10);
  com.add_channel(mist1::Channel("EXT_ILK", 'x', 1, &dummyFunc, &get_ext_ilk));  //To read interlock status
}

void loop() {
  if (Serial.available()) {
    com.respond_to_input_message();
  }  
}
```

The `respond_to_input_message()` method is as follows:

```
void mist1::Communication::respond_to_input_message() {
  char inputMessage[128];
  get_serial_data(inputMessage);

  char keyword = inputMessage[0];

  if (keyword == 'c') {
    Serial.println(get_all_channel_names());
  } else if (keyword == 'i') {
    Serial.println(get_all_channel_identifiers());
  } else if (keyword == 'n') {
    Serial.println(_com_name);
  } else if (keyword == 'q') {
    // Query.

    // Find what the user is querying for.
    int numberOfChannels = get_number_of_channels_queried(inputMessage);

    // Read input message.
    unsigned precisions[numberOfChannels];
    char channelIdentifiers[numberOfChannels];
    unsigned channelNumbers[numberOfChannels];

    String messageToReturn = "o";

    for (unsigned channelIndex = 0; channelIndex < numberOfChannels; channelIndex++) {
      for (unsigned i=0; i < _number_of_channels; i++) {
        if ((char)_all_channels[i].get_channel_identifier() == channelIdentifiers[channelIndex]){
          if (_all_channels[i].get_channel_number() == channelNumbers[channelIndex]){
            float valueToOutput = _all_channels[i].call_get_func();
            char * buff = float2s(valueToOutput, precisions[channelIndex]);
            char valueToPrint[1 + 1 + precisions[channelIndex] + 1 + 1 + 1]; // sign(1) + digit(1) + precision + exponent(1) + sign(1) + termination character(1).
            memset(valueToPrint, '\0', (1 + 1 + precisions[channelIndex] + 1 + 1 + 1));
            convert_scientific_notation_to_mist1(buff, valueToPrint, precisions[channelIndex]);
            String new_addition = (String) channelIdentifiers[channelIndex] + (String) channelNumbers[channelIndex] + valueToPrint;
            messageToReturn += new_addition;
            break;
          }     
        }
      }
    }
    messageToReturn += "\r\n";

    Serial.print(messageToReturn);
}
```

I have already tested with multiple Arduinos, cables, and USB ports.

What is going on here? Why is the Arduino ignoring the first message and responding only to subsequent messages?

Comment: idk, but i often see "throwaway" first items on serial port code...

Comment: What's a throwaway first item? As in a message we don't care about?

Comment: exactly. empty ones are common.

Answer (score 0):

When you open the arduino serial, it restarts. So you have to wait the end of restart (sleep 2s). All you write during this time should be lost.

Note that when restart is finished, you may have garbage in serial buffer.

In your function `respond_to_input_message()` I dont see a response if the message is not recognized, you should had a response for debug.

I mention a last problem I came across; with my (chinese = CH340 USB/serial) nano I could not reliably use a higher speed than 9600 bauds with pySerial.

Good luck.